# Как правильно использовать 9Patch

Tags: android

Есть картинка такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как сделать так чтобы я при указании параметров **ширины** и **высоты**, данная картинка всегда была такой, то есть, края всегда были круглыми.

А то у меня при размере 200 на 40 допустим, получается что углы у него не круглые, а **ромбовидные**... Как правильно нужно в 9Patch обрезать ее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идете например [сюда](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) и настраиваете область которая должна тянуться, можно заодно её уменьшить (Trim) ибо она у вас больно длинная.